# how to create multiple video popups with magnific popup

Tags: video, popup, magnific-popup

good people,
i have been struggling a bit with magnific popup plugin.
All is working as it should i guess (using it first time), im using for vimeo videos.
But, is it possible to open more than one video at ones? in some cases there are few video who belong to same category and would like to open them all vertically.

[example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rcy4.png)

i did find a solution to do like a gallery, and then you can change video by clicking arrows left and right, but still you have only one video open at once... so thats not a real option.